# Is there any prevalent logging packages in PL/SQL similar to java and .Net counterparts

Tags: oracle, best-practices, plsql

Normally in java or C# , I would use a following construct when try and catch errors.

Bad Exception Handling in C# and Java

```
try
{
  // do something
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Good Exception Handling in Java and C#

```
try
{

}
catch(ArgumentException ex)
{
  log(ex);
  // java throw
  throw ex;
 // in C#, throw only, is better since it keeps stack trace 
 throw;

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // this is catch ALL others block
  log(ex);
  // java throw
  throw ex;
 // in C#, throw only, is better since it keeps stack trace 
 throw;
}
```

In C# and java , I would use logging libraries. 
java : log4j, 
see others 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042450/what-log4j-alternative-logging-libraries-are-available

.Net : log4net, Nlog etc

In PL/SQL

Bad Exception Handling

```
BEGIN
-- Do Something
EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin
   WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN  
   null;
   WHEN OTHERS THEN  
   null;
END;
```

Good Exception Handling

```
BEGIN
-- Do Something
EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin
   WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN  
   LOG
   RAISE 

   WHEN OTHERS THEN  
   LOG
   RAISE 
END;
```

a simple google search brings log4plsql package : http://log4plsql.sourceforge.net/

- Are there any other libraries?
- Are they prevalent in PL/SQL programming?

[Oracle Documentation for Error Handling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/07_errs.htm) does not give hints about logging.

It gives following sentence and uses dbms_output.put_line for logging:

> "Sometimes, you want to reraise an exception, that is, handle it
>   locally, then pass it to an enclosing block. For example, you might
>   want to roll back a transaction in the current block, then log the
>   error in an enclosing block."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prevalent?  No.  It's not uncommon, however, to write a procedure like so:

```
create or replace procedure write_to_log
  (p_entry_point in varchar,
   p_log_type    in varchar,
   p_message     in varchar)
as
pragma autonomous_transaction
begin
  insert into my_log_file
    (entry_point, log_type, message, log_timestamp)
  values
    (p_entry_point, p_log_type, p_message, systimestamp);
  commit;
end;
```

Then you can add calls to `write_to_log` where needed throughout the code.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `DBMS_UTILITY` package:

```
FORMAT_CALL_STACK Function
FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE Function
FORMAT_ERROR_STACK Function$
```

However, you have to implement any logging functionality by yourself.

[DBMS_UTILITY Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#CHDGHICD)